# How can I securely store my AWS keys for an app on AppHarbor?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, appharbor

I am building an app that needs to upload files to S3. Initially, I had my secret key in the web.config file. Since they key has access to my entire account, I am realizing that instead I should rely on the IAM services to just generate a user for accessing a bucket.

However, this doesn't solve the problem of storing the key in plain text. How can I manage it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [IAM permissions to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html) *do* solve your problem because the user that you'll create will be only allowed to access this specific bucket - it can't do any harm to your account and you don't have to store the access/secret keys on the machine.

Further, you can [restrict access to a bucket to a specific IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3).

Comment: But if the key is compromised, won't someone be able to access and modify the contents of the bucket? And the IP restriction looks good, I'll have to investigate.

Comment: If someone gets your access-key & secret-key your account will be compromised regardless what you do. But the nice thing about using IAM roles is that it doesn't involve *your* user